# Реализация списка избранных карточек

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня два фрагмента c RecyclerView + карточки. Первый фрагмент содержит полный список карточек, во втором должны быть избранные. Данные карточек первого фрагмента заполняются из Firebase Database. Считываться и обновляться они должны при наличии интернета. 
Также в проекте есть SQLite, где будут храниться избранные. На этом этапе у меня возникли трудности. В самой карточке только краткие описания. Для ее открытия я повесила слушатель и вызываю активити из адаптера. Весь код адаптера:

```
public abstract class PoemAdapterAbs extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder> {
private List<ModelPoem> list;

public PoemAdapterAbs(List<ModelPoem> list) {

    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_poem, parent, false));

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelPoem modelPoem = list.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(modelPoem.title);
    holder.poem.setText(modelPoem.poem);
    holder.years.setText(modelPoem.years);
    holder.subject.setText(modelPoem.subject);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class PoemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView poem;
    CardView cv;
    TextView subject;
    TextView years;
    ImageView subject_image;
    ImageView years_image;

    PoemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        poem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
        years = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
        subject_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_subject);
        years_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_years);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ReadActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", title.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("poem", poem.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("years", years.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("subject", subject.getText().toString());

                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

код активити, где полного чтения карточки. Тут есть кнопка heart, по нажатию на которую данные записываются в избранное.

```
    public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv_Title;
    TextView tv_Poem;
    TextView tv_Years;
    ImageView iv_heart;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public ReadActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tv_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_Poem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
        tv_Years = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
        iv_heart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_heart);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String poem = intent.getStringExtra("poem");
        String years = intent.getStringExtra("years");

        tv_Title.setText(title);
        tv_Poem.setText(poem);
        tv_Years.setText(years);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);


        View.OnClickListener heartOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               addPoemFromSQLite();
               }
        };

        iv_heart.setOnClickListener(heartOnClick);

        }
  public void addPoemFromSQLite() {


    }
```

код DBHelpera

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FAVORITE_DATABASE";
    public static final String POEM_TABLE = "POEM_TABLE";

    public static final String POEM_TITLE_COLUMN = "POEM_TITLE";
    public static final String POEM_POEM_COLUMN = "POEM_POEM";
    public static final String POEM_SUBJECT_COLUMN = "POEM_SUBJECT";
    public static final String POEM_YEARS_COLUMN = "POEM_YEARS";
    public static final String POEM_KEY_COLUMN = "POEM_KEY_COLUMN";

    private static final String POEM_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + POEM_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POEM_TITLE_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + POEM_POEM_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + POEM_SUBJECT_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + POEM_YEARS_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + POEM_KEY_COLUMN + " INTEGER);";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(POEM_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT);
    }

        public void savePoem(ModelPoem poem){
            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

            newValues.put(POEM_TITLE_COLUMN, poem.getTitle());
            newValues.put(POEM_POEM_COLUMN, poem.getPoem());
            newValues.put(POEM_SUBJECT_COLUMN, poem.getSubject());
            newValues.put(POEM_YEARS_COLUMN, poem.getYears());
            newValues.put(POEM_KEY_COLUMN, poem.getKey());

            getWritableDatabase().insert(POEM_TABLE, null, newValues );
        }
```

Карточки должны идентифицироваться по ключам. В модели есть поле long key. Оно же совпадает с ключем в firebase. Такой же ключ должен быть и  SQLite.

Как мне передать этот ключ в ReadActiviity, чтобы положить его в SqLite?

Comment: Вопрос лишь в том как передать значение в активити?

Answer (score 0):

Можно адаптер реализовать как то так

```
public abstract class PoemAdapterAbs extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder> {
    public interface PoemObserver {
        void onPoemClick(ModelPoem modelPoem);
    }

    private List<ModelPoem> list;
    private PoemObserver poemObserver;

    public PoemAdapterAbs(List<ModelPoem> list, PoemObserver poemObserver) {
        this.list = list;
        this.poemObserver = poemObserver;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new PoemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_poem, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PoemAdapterAbs.PoemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindHolder(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class PoemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView poem;
        CardView cv;
        TextView subject;
        TextView years;
        ImageView subject_image;
        ImageView years_image;
        ModelPoem modelPoem;

        PoemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            poem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            years = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
            subject_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_subject);
            years_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_years);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if(poemObserver!= null && modelPoem!= null){
                    poemObserver.onPoemClick(modelPoem);
                }
            });
        }

        public void bindHolder(ModelPoem modelPoem){
            this.modelPoem = modelPoem;
            title.setText(modelPoem.title);
            poem.setText(modelPoem.poem);
            years.setText(modelPoem.years);
            subject.setText(modelPoem.subject);
        }
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял, тебе нужно при нажатии на холдер что то передать туда из фрагмента?
Тогда во фрагменте надо делать как то так:

```
    PoemAdapterAbs adapter = new PoemAdapter(myPoemList, new PoemAdapterAbs.PoemObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onPoemClick(ModelPoem modelPoem) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ReadActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", modelPoem.title);
            intent.putExtra("poem", modelPoem.poem);
            intent.putExtra("years", modelPoem.years);
            intent.putExtra("subject", modelPoem.subject);
            //тут пихаешь нужные данные из фрагмента или активити
            intent.putExtra("mykey", mykey);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```